# JavaScript Canvas how to stroke special text

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want stroke Triple Line and Thin Thick Line text. How to do like this:

**Triple Line Text**

[image: Triple Line Text]

**Thin Thick Line Text**

[image: Thin Thick Line Text]

Thanks

Comment: Is this for Javascript?

Comment: Yes，for Javascript

Comment: for that kind of task you shoud use SVG not canvas... way better for resize and easier to code.

Comment: (⊙o⊙)…there is no way to replace canvas with SVG.......
I have solved the problem of drawing special lines for geometry2D,but no idea for text